# How can I get *ALL* the info for available packages in apt at once?

Tags: apt, apt-cache

I would like to get the details about all the available packages in apt without installing them. I know that `apt-cache search .` would give me the list and description of all the available packages. However, I'm interested in the same list but with the most recent version. Is it possible?

I also know that I can loop over the package names and run `apt-cache show pkgName`, but I do not want to make multiple queries to apt-cache. I want to query it only once or use another tool or another available resource that could give me this info.

Edit: I would like the output to be something like this on each line:

```
package1, version
package2, version
...
```

And `version`, is the most recent version available in apt repository.

Comment: Do I misunderstand you or `apt-cache show .` helps?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I like the output to be something like this on each line: `packageName, most recent version`

Comment: This seems like an [XY Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). What is the purpose of this output format? Why would anybody want a list of thousands of package names and their current versions?

Comment: Totally agree with @user535733 . Please also note that the output of `apt-cache policy .` might be a bit easier to parse than the one of `apt-cache show`, in case you want to script its parsing.

Answer (score 0):

One easy answer to your question is to use `dpkg` instead of `apt`. `apt` will happily do all the logic and keep track of the versions precisely so you needn't muck around with such tedious details.

This particular command shows currently-installed versions, not available-for-upgrade (use `apt list --upgradeable` for that)

Try `dpkg -l | grep ii | awk '{print$2, $3}' | sed 's/ /, /'`

- Use `dpkg -l` to get the complete list of packages and versions in your package database
- Limit the output by showing only installed (ii) packages: `grep ii`
- Use awk to print only the second and third columns with : `awk '{print$2, $3}'`
- Insert your comma using sed: `sed 's/ /, /'`